# Ruby on Rails and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have read all answers for this topic, but I beg your help bc I still haven't find a solution. I create vote counter that will read from model increase likes counter and write updated counter++ to model.
I have `index.html.erb`

```
<div class="row">
<div id="tasks"><%= render @like %></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div id="like-form"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4">
    <%= link_to new_like_path, remote: true do %>
      <button class="btn btn-default">New</button>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

model schema:

```
create_table "likes", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "count"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

I have `LikesController`

```
def new
    if Like.first.count.to_i >= 0 
    then Like.create(count: "0")
    end 
    @like = Like.first.count.to_i
    @like++
    Like.update(0, :count => @like.to_s)
  end
```

`new.js.rb` file

```
    $('#like-form').html("<%= j (render 'form') %>");
$('#like-form').slideDown(350);
```

And I have `_form.html.erb`

```
<%= @like  %>
```

It doesn't want to render and I got

> 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement
>   :to_partial_path.

I am pretty new in rails, hope it all makes sense. I have heard about different ways to implement this task, but please help me to fix provided approach: to render form w/ ruby variable to html.

Comment: Why is the `count` column of type `string`?

Comment: The increment operator (++) does not exist in ruby or rails. You would have to use `@like+=1`.

Comment: I suggest to review a bit Ruby syntax before moving onto rails, especially as Menelik says, `++` doesn't exist in Ruby, also `then` is not a keyword I see used while on IFs, although valid, it'really weird to see that. Last but not list, I believe you have a big issue with last like in `new` method: `Like.update(0, :count => @like.to_s)` it's not even clear what are you trying to achieve with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to render an instance variable, you can write:

```
<div id="tasks"><%= @like %></div>
```

Also, your count column should be of type integer. If the count column is of type integer you can set the default value to 0 in your database. Here are the steps to go about doing this:

1. In your console type: rails generate migration ChangeCountTypeInLike
2. In your migration file add:

   ```
   remove_column :likes, :count, :integer
   add_column :likes, :count, :integer, default: 0
   ```
3. Then run `rake db:migrate` in your console

Since your `count` column is now of type integer and the default value of this column is now 0. You can change your `new` action in your controller to:

```
@like = Like.create
@like.increment!(:count)
```

Rails has an [increment](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment!) method you can use. Also you should reference what you are trying to like, I don't know how this code is of any use if you're not liking something.

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with:

```
$('#like-form').html("<%= j (render 'form') %>");
$('#like-form').slideDown(350);
```

But if you are just trying to update your likes, you can just write:

```
$("div#tasks).text(<%= j(@like) %>);
```

If you can describe what you are trying to achieve I can help you more.